# fetch selected feilds from the list

Tags: spring-data-jpa, crud

```
[{"uSID":1,"userId":"12","firstname":"shiva","lastname":"shubham","email":"shiva","phone":"586868768","active":"y","profile":{"pRID":98,"profileId":"78","profileName":"sh","paddress":"pune","surname":"sharma","pfname":"master"},"branch":{"bRID":2,"branchName":"zende","branchCode":"7899","add2":null,"city":null,"baddress":null,"add1":null}},
```

this is my json format.in my Users there is a foreign key profile and branch .while fetching by using  /geAllUsers i have to show just few fields of branch for ex.

```
"bRID":2,"branchName":"zende","branchCode":"7899
```

which kind of code i use to write in a spring data jpa

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-json-view-annotation

Answer (score 0):

Since the information provided is limited, I am assuming that the JSON you posted is current output from your API to user.

This can be handled in below two ways

- **Add custom serialiser** - You can add custom serialiser and annotate the DAO/Entity class with it. This works while converting object to JSON. So, spring returns all fields but only selected fields will be serialised to json and returned to user.
  Drawback - Since you are adding annotation at class level, this would be applicable to every instance where this object is returned. To handle this you can create a DAO, add annotation to DAO, transform object to DAO and return DAO.
- **User mapping frameworks like ModelMapper or MapStruct** - This would be the more ideal way. This happens within service unlike previous one which happens while serialisation. You can create a DAO class as required (with fields you want) and use any of these frameworks to transform your entity to required DAO. Code will be very minimal and optimised. And you can use it only when you want to limit fields.

You can get lot of tutorials on internet regarding both the above.

P.S. - If you are thinking which one to use between ModelMapper and Mapstruct, Mapstruct has better performance while ModelMapper is easy to implement.